# How to iterate through Document Libraries where specific user have access

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, user

In a site collection, i have couple of Document libraries like DocA, DocB and DocC. There are couple of users who have permission to access specific Document libraries. For example User A have access to DocA and DocB only and User B have access to DocC only. Now my question is how can I iterate through document libraries for User A only i.e, Document libraries DocA and DocB.

I want sample code to understand?

Comment: Are you looking for Server side code or client object model code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript Client Object Model Code:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var lists = clientContext.get_web().get_lists();
clientContext.load(lists);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onListSuccess, onListFail); 
function onListSuccess() {
var listInfo = 'Lists: \n\n';;
var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var list = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listInfo += list.get_title() + '\n';
    }
    alert(webInfo);    
}

function onListFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Server Side Code Example:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://aissp2013/sites/Team/"))
{
    SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
    SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;
    foreach(SPList list in lists)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If the server side code is run in a SharePoint context for example in a SharePoint page, then user will see only the lists in which user has permissions. SharePoint will automatically security trim the results. Since you may be running this code from a console application using an administrator account, that is the reason all lists will be shown. The other way to check whether a user has permissions on a list using console app is to use `SPList.DoesUserHavePermissions`.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
 {
    using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
    {
       SPBasePermissions perms = SPBasePermissions.AddListItems
                               | SPBasePermissions.ApproveItems
                               | SPBasePermissions.CancelCheckout
                               | SPBasePermissions.DeleteListItems
                               | SPBasePermissions.DeleteVersions
                               | SPBasePermissions.EditListItems
                               | SPBasePermissions.Open
                               | SPBasePermissions.OpenItems
                               | SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems
                               | SPBasePermissions.ViewVersions;


       string listUrl = web.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "shared documents";
       SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);

       // Be sure the current user has permission to check permissions.
       if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions))
       {
          foreach (SPGroup group in web.Groups)
          {
             foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
             {
                // Check another user's permissions.
                bool hasPermission = list.DoesUserHavePermissions(user, perms);
                Console.WriteLine("{0, -5}  {1}", hasPermission, user.LoginName);
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
 Console.Write("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms436062(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: But this code will return all the libraries in the site. As i said in question, I want to iterate only those libraries where User A have access. how i can do this using server side code?

Comment: @SPBeginer, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! As i am beginner, I just want to confirm one thing, In this line of code: list.DoesUserHavePermissions(user, perms). "user" parameter will be the currently login user to SP site, is that correct? or it will be the currently windows login account user? just clarify me! Because SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser; returns UserAccount for user currently logedin using windows login account?

Comment: The code is getting all the users in a group and checking their permissions. SPContext is relevant in a code which is run from within SharePoint for example a webpart. Finally,  a console application is run using windows user.